# Switching to Activity1 (RecyclerView) to Activity2 (RecyclerView)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Please help me into this problem. I have a 2 activity with RecyclerView each of them. My problem, when I open the Activity1 and pressed back then open the Activity2, it loads but when scrolling the application is unfortunately closing.

Each activity has Adapter and Holder. Did I forgot to finish the activity onBackPressed? What code should I put and where to put? Thank you!

Activity.java

```
 package com.bne;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

    public class Festivals extends AppCompatActivity {

        String[] names;
        String[] location;
        int[] images ={};
        String[] date;
        String[] about;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.festivals);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Festivals);

            names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.festival_name);
            location = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.festival_location);
            date = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.festival_date);
            about = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.festival_about);

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

            FestivalsAdapter adapter = new FestivalsAdapter(this, names, location, images, date, about);
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Adapter.java

```
package com.bne;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FestivalsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter 
<FestivalsHolder> {

    Context festivals;
    String [] name, location, date, about;
    int [] images;

    public FestivalsAdapter(Context festivals, String [] name, String  [] location, int [] images, String  [] date, String  [] about) {

        this.festivals = festivals;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.images = images;
        this.date = date;
        this.about = about;

    }

    @Override
    public FestivalsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.festivals_recycler, null);
        FestivalsHolder festivalsHolder = new FestivalsHolder(view);

        Typeface content = Typeface.createFromAsset(festivals.getAssets(), "fonts/cantarell.ttf");
        Typeface header = Typeface.createFromAsset(festivals.getAssets(), "fonts/avenir.ttf");

        festivalsHolder.name.setTypeface(header, Typeface.BOLD);
        festivalsHolder.location.setTypeface(content);
        festivalsHolder.date.setTypeface(content);
        festivalsHolder.about.setTypeface(content);

        return festivalsHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FestivalsHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.name.setText(name[position]);
        holder.location.setText(location[position]);
        holder.images.setImageResource(images[position]);
        holder.date.setText(date[position]);
        holder.about.setText(about[position]);

        holder.setPlacesItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(festivals, FestivalDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name", name[position]);
                intent.putExtra("Location", location[position]);
                intent.putExtra("Images", images[position]);
                intent.putExtra("Date", date[position]);
                intent.putExtra("About", about[position]);

                festivals.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return name.length;
    }
}
```

Holder.java

```
 package com.bne;

    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class FestivalsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageView images;
        TextView name, location, date, about;
        private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

        public FestivalsHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            images = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.festivals_image);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.festivals_name);
            location = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.festivals_location);
            date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.festivals_date);
            about = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.festivals_about);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(view, getLayoutPosition());

        }

        public void setPlacesItemClickListener (ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {

            this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;

        }
    }
```

LogCat:

```
07-28 21:31:16.602 30354-30354/com.bne E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.bne, PID: 30354
                                                                        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 7200012 byte allocation with 2024544 free bytes and 1977KB until OOM
                                                                            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2658)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2563)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:821)
                                                                            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:353)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:201)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:189)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:73)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:81)
                                                                            at com.bne.TerrainsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TerrainsAdapter.java:51)
                                                                            at com.bne.TerrainsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TerrainsAdapter.java:12)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6400)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6433)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5377)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5640)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:282)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:336)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:349)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:356)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:387)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Post you error log.

Comment: add the logcat output please

Comment: Logcat has been added. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem you have large size of images in your resources which is causing this error when you are loading in your adapter.

Only use images of the size required by your layout or else this error would cause often.